# How to address a databuffer from a pointer returned from Assembly to COBOL

Tags: assembly, cobol, mainframe

I have a COBOL program that call a Assembly module. This module returns a Pointer to some data (I'll call it 'buffer') obtained inside this module.
How can I address a variable in my working storage to this pointer and use the data?

In my COBOL caller I have something like:

Working Storage:

```
01 WK-MOD-AREA.
   03 WK-MOD-PTR          PIC 9(09) COMP VALUE 0.

01 WK-BUFFER-PTR          USAGE POINTER.
01 FILLER                 REDEFINES WK-BUFFER-PTR.
   03 WK-BUFFER-PTR-COMP  PIC 9(09) COMP.
01 WK-BUFFER-DATA         PIC X(5656) VALUE SPACES.
```

Procedure Division:

```
CALL 'MYMOD' USING WK-MOD-AREA.
```

MYMOD returns an address in WK-MOD-PTR.

I just tryed address the data using:

```
MOVE WK-MOD-PTR TO WK-BUFFER-PTR-COMP.

SET ADDRESS OF WK-BUFFER-PTR TO WK-BUFFER.
```

But it gives me the compiller error:

```
==000657==> IGYPS2161-S "ADDRESS OF" operand "WRK-BUFFER" 
was found as the receiving operand of a "SET" statement, 
but was not a level-01 or level-77 "LINKAGE SECTION" item.  
The statement was discarded.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SimonSobisch My bad... It's acctualy called by reference. Without 'quotation mark'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want but you can't change the address of an item in `WORKING-STORAGE SECTION`, these items have a fixed address and are allocated when the program is activated for the first time.
As your compiler told you already you can do this with items in `LINKAGE SECTION` as these have no fixed address and aren't allocated.

And depending on your actual use you may pass the `POINTER` directly to the program instead of an intermediate variable:

```
Working-Storage SECTION.

01 WK-BUFFER-PTR          USAGE POINTER.

LINKAGE SECTION.
01 WK-BUFFER-DATA         PIC X(5656) VALUE SPACES.

Procedure Division.

CALL 'MYMOD' USING WK-BUFFER-PTR.
SET ADDRESS OF WK-BUFFER-DATA TO WK-BUFFER-PTR.
```

Notes:

- You'll still have to make sure that the data is freed somewhere after using it (maybe by calling the allocating program with a parameter to free).
- You have to make sure that you don't access the field over the actual allocated length, if it isn't always 5656 Bytes. To ensure this you may use reference-modification `WK-BUFFER-DATA (1:actual-length)` or a table with variable size `DEPENDING ON` (especially useful with `OCCURS UNBOUNDED`).

Comment: Props for reminding me of my COBOL class some 25 years ago.